# I want to use the Corpus function, but I am unable to install the tm package for text mining in R 3.4.2

Tags: r

The error:

> Warning in install.packages :   cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/tm_0.7-1.zip': HTTP status was '404 Not Found' Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) :    cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/tm_0.7-1.zip' Warning in install.packages :   download of package ‘tm’ failed

Comment: Can you please edit the question stating what you have tried and what is the error

Comment: Basically, i tried installing tm package using- install.packages("tm") but i get the error above mentioned. Also, going through similar queries, i came across quite a few suggestions to update my R version but since i am using the latest R version, that shouldn't be a problem. So, i really can't figure out what the issue is.

Comment: Do you have internet conection?

Comment: Yes i the connection is absolutely fine since i am able to install rest of the packages

Answer (score 0):

It can happen sometimes. My suggestion is to download the `.zip` or `.tar.gz` file from CRAN and install it through the user interface:

```
Tools -> Install packages -> Install from: "Package Archive File"
```